# Programmatically execute commands in Windows Terminal using wsl

Tags: c#, python-3.x, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I am trying to run a python program in Ubuntu using wsl. I need to access Windows Terminal from C# application and execute commands in wsl. I am able to open the Windows Terminal. But cannot programmatically execute multiple commands after it.

I tried the below code. But the StandardInput.WriteLine is not working as I expected.

```
StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"wt.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                Arguments = "wsl"
            }
        })
        {
            proc.Start();                  
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();                
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd Ubuntu/MyProject");
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("python3 MyProgram.py ABC.wav");

        }
```

Comment: While it is possible to specify a starting profile (using `wt -p "name of profile"`) it is not possible to communicate with this session. The only thing you could do is create a profile which launces `python3 MyProgram.py ABC.wav` but ....

Comment: Do you mean I can pre-configure Windows Terminal to execute "MyProgram.py ABC.wav" every time it is open?

Comment: There is a nifty little commandline tool developed by Neosmart called [RuninBash](https://neosmart.net/RunInBash/) that can accomplish what you need.  Just download the exe, rename it to $.exe, and then you can make calls to the WSL console by prefixing your commands with "$ ".  For example, you could run the last line of code in your example script using the below command:

$ python3 MyProgram.py ABC.wav

Comment: [RuninBash](https://neosmart.net/RunInBash/) worked like a charm. I ran the RuninBash exe in the background. After that, " $ python3 MyProgram.py ABC.wav" just worked. (I used cmd.exe instead of wt.exe). Thanks for the assist.